# Using double quotes in MySQL Match against to escape reserved characters

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find obtain better search results with MATCH AGAINST in MySQL.  Where the words contain reserved characters such as -, ( and ) I enclose them in double quotes. However, this makes it not possible to use the + sign on any subsequent words.

For example the following throws an error due to the + sign before corporation:

MATCH (`SomeField`) AGAINST (+"hyphen-word" +corporation' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

I have tried escaping the hyphen with single and double backslash but it doesn't work, the hyphen still seems to be interpreted as an exclude sign (or at least it is not recognised as a character).

I am aware of other options such as LIKE etc but I would like to use MATCH AGAINST if possible.

Is there a way of escaping reserved characters and still use the + operator (as per example above)?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, using brackets works without wildcard / * works but not if wildcard is added e.g. +("corporation") does work but +("corporation*") does NOT work (does not match with corporations for example).  I will try to include the table description in a bit

Comment: If the word is in double quotes the wildcard does not work, MySQL throws an error.  Whether using the brackets or not the wildcard does not seem to work when using double quotes.  The database is COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB.  The scenario may be outside what MATCH AGAINST can handle but that would make it quite limited.  You basically have to choose between handling reserved chars such as -, ( and ) OR use the + and * operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any "escaping" in FT syntax.  Instead, sanitize the input...

- Remove any punctuation that conflicts with what FT wants.
- Consider replacing such punctuation with `_` or some other "letter".
- Remove (or don't use `+` with) any "words" shorter than `innodb_ft_min_token_size`.
- Decide whether to disable `innodb_ft_enable_stopword` or to use `innodb_ft_user_stopword_table`

If necessary, add an extra column to the table, just for the sanitized text for FT.  (Example:  an FT index on text in HTML after stripping out all the tags.)

Another FT tip:

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST("hyphenated word")
  AND       col    LIKE "%hyphenated-word%"
```

is a way to get the speed of Fulltext and still filter out things that got through the FT.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right sanatizing the input seems to be the way to go.  Removing any hyphens and parantheses whilst not perfect does work.  I discovered that whilst the fulltext search normally requires a match to start with the search string (i.e. no wildcard at start) it works to remove parantheses at start presumably due to it being a reserved characters. E.g. 'something in*' will match '(something in parantheses)'.  So for now the solution is to remove hyphen and parantheses from the search string before applying it in MATCH AGAINST.

Comment: @ChrisE - I don't see `+`, nor `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.  So I suspect that only the word "something" matched and that the parentheses and "in" were ignored.

Answer (score 0):

**Your SQL query is missing a single quote** (the expression as to be enclosed in single quotes). That's  what's causing the error (not the + sign before "corporation"... it was the first "+" sign actually).

This is your query fixed (notice the single quote added in the beginning of the expression):

```
MATCH (SomeField) AGAINST ('+"hyphen-word" +corporation' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So, yes you **can** use + signs on any subsequent words.

Just remember that if you want to use wildcards (*), you cannot use double quotes.

Another example:

```
MATCH (SomeField) AGAINST ('+"hyphen-word" +"corporation" +startwith*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This would match

> In a hyphen-word a corporation can startwithanything

But would NOT match

> In a hyphen-word all corporations can startwithanything

**Be aware that there's a bug in some MySQL / MariaDB versions: using double quotes for exact match makes the server crash.**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123414/fulltext-index-innodb-double-quote-search-memory-exhaustion
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76423

The example queries above make my server crash after a while (MariaDB 10.5.19, with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS).

If I want to match *"Daniel Day-Lewis"*, I have to do:

```
MATCH (SomeField) AGAINST ('+day +lewis +Daniel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Hope this helps!